# Relation between LCM of terms of sequence with sum of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any relation between LCM of some arbitrary sequence and sum of elements of sequence ? How to find the LCM if only sequence sum is given in short time ?

Comment: $\operatorname{lcm}(a,a)=a$ and $\operatorname{lcm}(1,a)=a$, but $a+a\neq 1+a$ in general.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general there's no such relation. You cannot find the LCM if only the sum is given.

Comment: Actually I am solving the problem on SPOJ that asked to find the inverse of divisor sum function so I needed this relation.